# Bake Panel in Render Properties doesn't pop up

Tags: rendering

I've been trying to bake my object so I can create realistic renders. However, the bake panel that should be found in the render properties refuses to pop up, no matter what. Am I doing something wrong? Please help me! Thanks <3

[image: Image in Object Mode]

[image: Image in Edit Mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Upgrade blender](https://www.blender.org/download/).

Cycles baking was first added in blender [v2.71](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71) and you are using 2.70. The current blender version is 2.78c.

Baking is available in 2.70 if you switch the render engine to blender render, but using that will depend on the material setup you are trying to bake.